# How to write very complex SQL in a clean and maintainable way?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm in the database migration project.

I have to write very complex SQL in a maintainable way. The previous query is almost spaghetti.

I wanna make a view in the database but I have no authority.

So what I am thinking about is making a bridged database that is from the query result of the database.

After that, I made views in the bridged database.

is it inefficient? or is there any nice way to deal with a complex database queries?

Comment: Post examples of tables and queries, if you keep the question so generic, is way too complex to help you, [please, read this "how to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to write SQL in a maintainable way is a very broad question. It really depends on what you need to do. My suggestion is to document / comment every little thing you do in the query. Also, include a comment on top of the file explaining in detail what the query is trying to do and how it does it.

As other users suggested, creating temp tables is a great way of simplifying a query. First, you can split the query in stages and design each stage to be a logical step towards the end goal. More importantly, you can query the temp tables and review the result of each stage, which makes fixing errors so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't create views, see whether CTE (Common Table Expression, i.e. the WITH factoring clause) makes things easier to read & maintain. Just a short example:

instead of

```
select ...
from (select deptno
      from dept
     ) join ...
```

use

```
with depts as
  (select deptno
   from dept
  )
select ...
from depts d join ...
```

as it enables you to use the same DEPTS CTE any number of times that long query requires (instead of repeating/writing it many times separately).

---

Your idea about the "bridged database" calls for usage of **database links**. Operations over them are usually slower than when you have data in your own database. Updates can be painfully slow.

---

Maybe you'd better ask someone (a DBA?) to let you create those views?

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked for permissions to create a view? Sometimes DBAs can be friendly!

Assuming you've already tried, do you have permissions to create temp tables? It may be a workaround to creating a view.